# MySQL server has gone away when upload image larger than 1.0MB

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

I get warnings while uploading image size 1.5MB and the image did not store into the database, it works fine for image smaller than 1MB.

Please help because I stuck for few days with these warnings.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

print_r($_FILES);

//connect to the database//

try {
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=forms1', 'root', 'root',array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'));
$file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name']; 

$upload=0;

for($count = 0; $count < count($_FILES['image']); $count++)
{
if(!empty($_FILES['image']['name'][$count])){
$image_name[$count] = addslashes($_FILES['image']['name'][$count]); echo '<br \>';
$image_size[$count] = @getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$count]);
$error[$count] = $_FILES['image']['error'][$count];

if($image_size[$count] == FALSE  || ($image_size[$count]) == 0)
    echo "That's not an image";

$upload++;
echo $upload;

// Temporary file name stored on the server
 $tmpName[$count]  = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$count];

// Read the file
$fp[$count]   = fopen($tmpName[$count], 'r');
$data[$count] = fread($fp[$count], filesize($tmpName[$count]));
$data[$count] = addslashes($data[$count]);
fclose($fp[$count]);

// Create the query and insert into database.

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO files (name,image) VALUES (:name,:image)');
$stmt->execute(array('name' => $image_name[$count],'image' => $data[$count]));

    if(!$stmt)
    echo "Problem uploding the image. Please check your database";  
}
}
} catch (PDOException $e) {
print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage();
die();
}

?>
```

These are the warnings I get:

```
Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): MySQL server has gone away in C:\xampp\htdocs\testing\test.php on line 56

Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): Error reading result set's header in C:\xampp\htdocs\testing\test.php on line 56
```

The warning point to this line:

```
$stmt->execute(array('name' => $image_name[$count],'image' => $data[$count]));
```

Comment: have u checked php.ini file.u can increase the upload size there.

Comment: Do not store files in database.

Comment: @YourCommonSense is right .just store the reference of the image in your database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is fairly simple:

## Do not store files in database.

this way you will solve not one but dozen problems at once.
Just because relational database is not the place for binary files.

this error message you are getting is a **warning sign**  says: "You are burden your server with huge unnecessary load". And this load will be even increased when you will need your files back.

While stored in filesystem, binary files will hamper noone and - most important - served blazingly fast, cost you no precious resources

Comment: Thank You for your answer. But can you please guide me or provide me the best solution on how to upload and retrieve image? any link or sample code that I can refer?

Comment: it is usually so simple that noone bothers with any tutorial, as far as I know. Just create a directory to store files, than use `move_uploaded_file()` to move uploaded file there, storing *filename* in database. And then when you need to show it to user - just link it like this `<img src = '/images/$stored_filename'>` - that's all

Comment: @alvin890101 the real answer why this happen is this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/packet-too-large.html this is 1 Mb on default.. but using an database as file system is bad.. but filesystem doenst respect innodb's rollback, so you could have phantom files what you need to handle yourself then.. "Your Common Sense" but still +1 for this answer

Answer (score 0):

While storing the image in the `Database` increases server load.It is not a good practice too.You have to store the image in a folder and store the path or name of that image in your `Database`.The important thing you have to consider in this case is that,you  have to provide some means to uniquely identify each image.Other wise ,the image having the same name will get replaced with the new one in your folder.